# Current reversal in galvanic cell according to Nernst equation

Tags: electrochemistry

In a galvanic cell with zinc, zinc sulphate solution and copper, copper sulphate solution, if at equilibrium concentration of zinc sulphate solution increased/copper sulphate solution decreased, will current flow in the opposite direction (from copper rod to zinc rod)?
(The value of cell potential according to Nernst equation will be negative in this case, and to re-establish equilibrium, current should flow from copper rod to zinc rod. )

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the answer is yes, at least in ideal circumstances. As a practical matter, it would be more likely with a pair of metals and their salt solutions that were closer in reduction potentials, e.g., tin and lead or perhaps nickel and copper. And you are correct about the Nernst equation being involved.